# Como leer apropiadamente un objeto Json son Java Spring, e identificar si se trata de un objeto o una lista

Tags: java, json, spring

Estoy necesitando ayuda con un servicio rest en Java Spring. Recibo un Json (el cual convertí en sus respectivas clases java con "jsonschema2pojo.org" y me creo 30 clases), lo manejo por medio de una clase parametrizada.

Pero cuando quiero leer el response, no sabe si es un objeto o es una lista. El tema es que el principal es un objeto pero adentro tiene otros objetos y listas. Entonces me da el siguiente error:

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error reading entity from input stream

Y mas abajo:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Numeric value (3376461333454861) out of range of int
> at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@6970140a; line: 1, column: 3601] (through reference chain: com.pabloburzomi.MLARestProductos.DTO.ProductoRest["results"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.pabloburzomi.MLARestProductos.DTO.Result["attributes"]->java.util.ArrayList[2]->com.pabloburzomi.MLARestProductos.DTO.Attribute["values"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.pabloburzomi.MLARestProductos.DTO.Value["source"])

Acá la clase genérica:

```
public abstract class RestRequest<T> {

    protected String urlApi;

    public RestRequest(String urlApi) {

        this.urlApi = urlApi;
    }

    public T executeRestCall() throws Exception {

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig().register(LoggingFeature.class));

        WebTarget webTarget = this.buildWebTarget(client);
        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        Response response = this.buildResponse(invocationBuilder);
        

        if (Status.OK.getStatusCode() != response.getStatus()) {
            throw new Exception(response.getStatusInfo().getReasonPhrase());
        }

        T responseT = this.buildResponseDTO(response);

        return responseT;

    }
    
    protected abstract T buildResponseDTO(Response response);
    

    private Response buildResponse(Builder invocationBuilder) {
        return invocationBuilder.get();
    }
    
    protected WebTarget buildWebTarget(Client client) {
        return client.target(getUrlApi());
    }

    public String getUrlApi() {
        return urlApi;
    }
}
```

Y acá la clase que da el error al intentar leer el objeto response:

```
public class VendedorRestRequest extends RestRequest<ProductoRest>{

    public VendedorRestRequest(String urlApi) {
        super(urlApi);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected ProductoRest buildResponseDTO(Response response) {
        

        ProductoRest ra = response.readEntity(ProductoRest.class);
        
        return ra;      
        
    }
}
```

Pienso que tendría que tener una forma de que preguntar si el objeto response es objeto o es lista y tratarlo a cada uno a su manera, pero no se cual es.

Gracias, si alguien sabe orientarme muy agradecido.

Comment: Objeto! == JSON. Recuerda que JSON es un formato de texto. Si recibes o tienes una cadena de texto en formato JSON, podrías revisar el primer carácter de la cadena, si es un `{` entonces se trata de un *objeto* de Javascript, por el contrario si es un `[`, se trata de un *array* de Javascript. O al menos es lo que se me ocurre en este momento. Saludos

Comment: El error que tienes no es porque tienes listas, es porque tienes una propiedad que no soporta el valor numérico `3376461333454861`, ve el json de entrada y revisa la variable a la que se asigna ese valor,  puede que `jsonschema2pojo` te creara una variable `int`  que no soporta ese número, si es el caso pásalo a long o verifica el tamaño máximo y elije un tipo de dato acorde.

Comment: Mauricio Contreras si, es un objeto (esta entre "{}") que dentro tiene listas y otros objetos.

Comment: Roberto E Moran Roberto Moran si he leido esa repuesta que me das buscando en internet. Pero en la clase principal que me arma jsonschema2pojo (la que le tenes que poner vos el nombre) "results" es una lista por ejemplo, no un entero. Y después jsonschema2pojo crea una clase "Result" donde los atributos son String y hay varios Integer. Decís que los de esta última clase habría que cambiarles de Integer a Long? Gracias por las respuestas!

Comment: Amigo Roberto E Moran Tenías toda la razón. Después de leer varias veces tu solución, entendí que tenía que buscar los datos que daba fuera de rango en el Json, y modificarlos en sus respectivas clases .java.  Gracias!! Solucionado.

Comment: @PabloPérezBurzomi Para evitar que la pregunta se quede sin respuesta, por favor escribe una respuesta con la solución que te ha arreglado el problema, explicándolo para que otras personas que se encuentren con un error similar tengan un rápido acceso a la información que necesitan. Recuerda que aquí estamos para compartir conocimiento y ayudar a todo el mundo! Además, pasadas 24h de tu propia respuesta podrás aceptarla!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es encontrar en las distintas clases .java los atributos que dan error porque fueron colocados como enteros y colocarlos como datos Long, ya que el error reside en que sobrepasa la cantidad aceptada para un entero.